# How to hide Dock icons from another Mac?

Tags: macos, catalina, dock

I have two Mac laptops logged into iCloud with same credentials. Now if I run e.g. Chrome then it will bring Chrome icon on the other laptop automatically.

That's a good feature to share data/work between them, but how do I disable this feature or hide the icon?

I'm running macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called "[Handoff](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209455)."

And Apple says:

> On your Mac: Choose Apple menu  > System Preferences, then click
> General. Select "Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud
> devices." On your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch: Go to Settings > General > AirPlay & Handoff, then turn on Handoff.